# How to apply fishers test between two data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, bioconductor

I have a data frames like following:

df1:

```
Type    S1  S2  
  CC    198 38
  Ch    163 43
   H    83  22
   J    24  14
  OS    33  7
   O    61  25
   R    100 24
   W    126 47
```

df2:

```
Type  S1    S2      
 CC  82     40
 Ch  117    35
 H   197    56
 J   256    64
 OS  247    71
 O   219    53
 R   180    54
 W   154    31
```

I applied fishers test for "CC"

```
fisher.test(matrix(c(198,82,38,40), nrow=2, ncol=2))

p-value = 0.0004191
```

But to do this for all other it is time taking process. I want to apply fishers test on all other types at a time and the result should look like following:

```
Type    Pvalue
CC  0.0004191
Ch  0.6978
H   0.8885
J   0.0226
OS  0.5491
O   0.07202
R   0.5013
W   0.02091
```

I got the answer for the above thing from the below answers. but I'm editing this with some more data now. What if the data looks like following:

df1:

```
Type    S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6
  CC    198 38  64  172 123 114
  Ch    163 43  67  140 108 98
   H    83  22  32  74  55  51
   J    24  14  17  21  23  15
  OS    33  7   11  30  23  17
   O    61  25  35  51  39  47
   R    100 24  41  84  57  67
   W    126 47  57  118 106 68
```

df2:

```
  Type  S1  S2  S3  S4  S5  S6
   CC   82  40  56  66  70  51
   Ch   117 35  53  98  85  67
    H   197 56  88  164 138 114
    J   256 64  103 217 170 150
   OS   247 71  109 208 170 148
    O   219 53  85  187 154 118
    R   180 54  79  154 136 98
    W   154 31  63  120 87  97
```

I want to apply fishers test for (S3,S4) and (S5,S6) also and get the p-value in the result. I can do it by taking only those columns and applying fishers test like the below answers (S1,S2). But I want to do it all at a time. In my original data I have many columns like this. Thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply()` feature of `R`. I assumed that, "Type" is a column name.

```
p_values <- sapply(1:nrow(df1), function(x) 
                   fisher.test(rbind(df1[x,-1],df2[x,-1]))$p.value)

# -1 inside the data frame (df1[x,-1] and df2[x,-1])   is for canceling out the Type column. If it is a rowname, then you don't need to add that...     


final <- cbind(df1$Type,as.data.frame(p_values)) 

colnames(final) <- c("Type","Pvalue")           

           Type       Pvalue
        1   CC 0.0004191119
        2   Ch 0.6978356887
        3    H 0.8884858252
        4    J 0.0225999709
        5   OS 0.5491422972
        6    O 0.0720173867
        7    R 0.5012970020
        8    W 0.0209138164
```

Hi @raju,

As for your second question (the multiple group case), the codes below can be used.

I defined a list named group to give you a chance to arrange the test columns. I mean, if you desire to test say S1 and S6, it is also possible for this setting. All you need to do is to add another group named **group4** and assign it a new vector **c("S1","S6")** .

```
group <- list(group1= c("S1","S2"),group2=c("S3","S4"),group3=c("S5","S6"))

for(i in 1:length(group)) {

    p_values <- sapply(1:nrow(df1), function(x) {

    a=cbind(df1[x,group[[i]][1]],df1[x,group[[i]][2]])

    b=cbind(df2[x,group[[i]][1]],df2[x,group[[i]][2]]) 

    fisher.test(rbind(a,b))$p.value }) 

    p <- as.data.frame(p_values)
    colnames(p) <- paste("PValue-Group-",i,sep="")

    if (i==1) {

        Type<-as.data.frame(df1$Type)
        colnames(Type) <- "Type"
        final <- cbind(Type,p) 

    }else{

        final <- cbind(final,p) 

    }

}

   Type PValue-Group-1 PValue-Group-2 PValue-Group-3
1   CC   0.0004191119   0.0005763285     0.31383253
2   Ch   0.6978356887   0.6504086114     0.52187626
3    H   0.8884858252   0.4619796458     0.64343778
4    J   0.0225999709   0.1457729970     0.49159715
5   OS   0.5491422972   0.3829413140     0.73695562
6    O   0.0720173867   0.1166177467     0.08215306
7    R   0.5012970020   0.9066133264     0.03416412
8    W   0.0209138164   0.7377283808     0.01096746
```

Comment: This looks great thank you. Would like to ask a question. If I have more columns like S3, S4, S5, S6 in Both the data frames and would like to apply fishers test on (S3,S4) and (S5,S6) does this work for more columns also?

Comment: I am not sure if understand you correctly but you can reach any column you want. It is just the matter of setting... Below, a way to set the column names you want to put inside the fisher test is written. Consider df1 and df2 has multiple columns called S1,S2,S3,S4,S5...

`c_name1 <- "S3"
c_name2 <- "S4"

p_values <- sapply(1:nrow(df1), function(x) {
    a=cbind(df1[x,c_name1],df1[x,c_name2])
    b=cbind(df2[x,c_name1],df2[x,c_name2])
                   fisher.test(rbind(a,b))$p.value })

final <- cbind(df1$Type,as.data.frame(p_values)) 

colnames(final) <- c("Type","Pvalue")`

Answer (score 2):

Easiest route to take is to `rbind` the two data frames, split on `Type` and apply the test on each element of the list, i.e.

```
full_df <- rbind(df1, df2)
lapply(split(full_df, full_df$Type), function(i) fisher.test(as.matrix(i[-1])))
```

or to just get the `p.value`,

```
sapply(split(full_df, full_df$Type), function(i) fisher.test(as.matrix(i[-1]))$p.valu)
#              CC           Ch            H            J            O           OS            R            W 
#    0.0004191119 0.6978356887 0.8884858252 0.0225999709 0.0720173867 0.5491422972 0.5012970020 0.0209138164
```

Comment: Hi Sotos, What if I have more columns in Both the data frames like S3,S4,S5,S6 and apply fishers test on (S3,S4) and (S5,S6) also along with (S1,S2). Does the above code for this type of data frame also?

Comment: Please update your question with any new requirements.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, I updated the question please check it.